# ASP.NET Core API model concept

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working on a sample app that exposes a restful API. I'm also using EF core to map entities mkd to a SQLite db.

Each entity has an ID property that is auto-generated and is unique.

The api expose a method for the creation of an entity by providing a model object. At the moment I'm using the same model that is mapped to EF Core (with the ID field included).

I honestly don't think that exposing the ID field during the creation of an entity is a good practice, so I thought to create another model  without the ID field that will be passed to the create method and then map it the model that EF is using.

Is it a good practice or is it too overkill?

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think it's wrong returning the Entity Id when creating it.
I always create Model classes and map them using AutoMapper which helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are essentially doing is the use of a DTO/ViewModel instead of the model object directly, and that is considered a good practice. It saves you from the problem of over-posting as well. Alternatively, you can choose to Bind specific properties as well - refer to https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETOverpostingMassAssignmentModelBindingSecurity.aspx

Comment: That's a really good article! Thanks. it was what I was looking for!